# Rails: Registration controller ignroing condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following code in my Registration controller (in the create method):

```
respond_to do |format|
  if discount_code && invalid_discount_code
    flash[:notice] = error_notification
    format.html { render action: "new" }
  elsif already_registered
    flash.now[:error] = error_notification
    format.html { redirect_to root_url }
  elsif @user.save
    events_history_hash = JSON.parse(@user.events_history)
    @user.skip_confirmation!
    sign_in @user
    if events_history_hash[Current_event_id.to_s]["payment"] && events_history_hash[Current_event_id.to_s]["payment"] == 0
      flash[:notice] = "Your complimentary registration for this event has been accepted."
      format.html { redirect_to root_url }
    elsif auto_approve
      payment = extract_payment_from_events_history_json(@user.events_history)
      format.html { redirect_to new_stripe_payment_path(:registration_payment => payment) }
    else
      EventMailer.send_email_to_admins_to_process_invite_request(current_user).deliver
      flash[:notice] = INVITE_REQUEST_RECEIVED
      format.html { redirect_to root_url }
    end
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

The code runs perfectly fine on my development environment (local to my MAC) and it redirects me to the payment page if auto_approve is true, but when I upload my code to the test server, it always executes

```
EventMailer.send_email_to_admins_to_process_invite_request(current_user).deliver
```

even though auto_approve is set to true. I verified this through running the console on the test server. What else should I be looking for?

## Possibly a Hack:

This is possibly a hack, but it fixed the problem. In test.rb, I changed the value of config.serve_static_assets from false to true (by default it was set to false in test.rb and production.rb but set to true in development.rb)

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

Answer (score 0):

How and where is `auto_approve` being set? Is this test server running under the production environment?

Comment: Per my question above, this is the test server, and it is running under the test environment. auto_approve is set when the discount code is checked against the codes table, if it's set to 'auto_approve', then auto_approve is set to true. This is not a scoping issue, because auto_approve is set to nil in the same method (create) before any of the conditionals, and I manually executed all the code using the console to see if it is properly set, and it is properly set, but that's the console not the actual runtime.